# Maven command for ear project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I have a EAR maven based project that its structure is like below :

```
------ root
  |
  |--- EAR
        |
        |---- EJB (JAR)
        |
        |---- WEB (WAR)
```

I want to make a goal for it that first clean all three EAR , EJB , WEB ,module 
then first install EJB after that  install WEB and at the end install EAR
because of their dependencies

how I have to do it in just one command line in maven?

here is my pom.xml for root

```
   <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>
<modules>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>ear</module>
</modules>

<properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Define the version of the EJB jar so that we don't need 
            to repeat ourselves in every module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RHAMavenBased</groupId>
            <artifactId>RHAMavenBased-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Define the version of the WAR so that we don't need to repeat 
            ourselves in every module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RHAMavenBased</groupId>
            <artifactId>RHAMavenBased-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the maven `multi module project` setup. Take a look into this tutorial [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html). Everything you need is configurable with this

**Edit**

There is an entry in your parent pom as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>RHAMavenBased</groupId>
        <artifactId>RHAMavenBased-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
```

I am not mistaken , here ${project.version} is the version of the parent pom that you are building and since it is specified in the parent pom, this dependency trickles down to all sub-modules which is not a good idea in your case, since the EJB project will have dependency on itself ( this is bad design ). Ideally a module should never be dependant on itself. So our first issue is redundant dependency in the modules. Secondly since this is defined in the parent pom and the `${project.version}` is being read from the parent pom, we may have version mismatches here or even un-synchronized jars in m2, target and on the build path.

Comment: thanks but I've done all these things , the problem is when I dont clean my ejb or war and try to install ear , it uses old ejb or war and it doesn't automatically install ejb and war , I manually must clean war , jar , install them and after that install ear , I want to write a command that do all these things

Comment: If it doesn't work like that then it means you have some different settings. Can you post your parent pom.xml here in the post? Where you have added the Modules in the pom.xml

Comment: every thing is working and every thing is ok , but when i want to clean or install any module i must do it one by one with IDE wizard , I want a command line like below that i can run it to do all jobs that i want : for example : mvn clean module jar,module war,module ear ,install module jar ,module war ,module ear but in correct syntax

Comment: If you fire the command `mvn clean install` on the parent pom, it will first clean all your module target directories and then install the relevant jars/wars in the consecutive directories. And you still havent shown the parent pom here

Comment: if I clean and install parent it uses the old Jar and war to make new ear , the ear itself will be new but with old jar

Comment: why my ejb depends on itself ? may you explain more ? Thanks for your help